# How to explain multiple copies of Harry and Hermione?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry and Hermione go back 3 hours, Prof Lupin and Prof Snape fail to see the two sets of the H&H characters. How can this be explained?

Comment: this question would be much improved if you added in when they go back, which book, why they went back, etc..  This would help people know what you're referencing and be better able to answer.

Comment: Also, why are you making an assumption that Lupin and Snape would have seen two sets? They took the pain to avoid that.

Answer (score 15):

The only way this question makes any sense is if what you're actually asking is "Why didn't Professors Lupin and Snape see Harry and Hermione twice **on the Marauder's Map**?", so I'll take a stab at answering that question.

We know that, when blank, the Marauder's Map simply resembles an old piece of parchment. We also know that when the enchantment is activated it shows all of the Hogwarts grounds, and shows dots that are labelled with the person's name.

The "past" (or should we say present?) Harry and Hermione are in the Shrieking Shack, which is in Hogsmeade (not within the Hogwarts grounds) and therefore not shown on the Marauder's Map. In that case, when Lupin and Snape were looking at the map (both in Lupin's office), there wouldn't have been two sets of Harry and Hermione shown.

It's also possible - and perhaps likely - that they simply didn't notice in their haste.

Comment: Looking for the same person twice on a map would be akin to noticing there were two Waldo/Wally in a scene after looking for them. Most people stop looking once they find what they are looking for.

Comment: At the time Harry casts his first "Expecto Patronum", he's quite close to himself near the lake and probably he's one of just a few persons out there. Wouldn't that have been noticed?

Comment: @ThomasWeller By that point in the events of the night, Lupin had turned into a werewolf and run off into the Forbidden Forest and Snape was unconscious, so there wasn't anybody looking at the map to notice.

Answer (score 2):

They didn't see both the Harrys or both the Hermiones at the same point of time. It's no big deal. Maybe at some point  they got a little surprised that Harry's tone or his body language or his location changed a lot in a short period of time, but it's the Harry Potter Universe; anything can happen. If the Profs were to note the two sets of Harry at all; it would be a greatly out-of-the-HpUnivese-guess.

This kind of "noticing" does not happen even in the real world many times (with identical twins).

Comment: "May be at some point of time they got a little suprized that the Harry's tone or his Body Language or his Location changed a lot in a short period of time" I really don't understand what you're talking about here - there's no point in those three hours where the two sets of Harry and Hermione are close enough for their to be any confusion. In fact, the only contact is when Harry sees his future self cast the Patronus from across the lake whilst being attacked by Dementors, but at this point Lupin has transformed into a werewolf and Snape is unconscious.

Comment: I have personally experienced people not noticing that my sister and I are two separate people. There was that one reenactment event, where my sister was wearing a 19th century empire-waisted gown and I was in huge 18th century panniers, and a lady exclaimed "there *are* two of them!" after seeing us together for the first time at the end of the day. (I still wonder, did she think she was seeing a quick-change artist or something?) That said, I don't see how this is relevant to the question of the Marauder's Map showing two sets of people at the same time.

Comment: Like the other answer says, the only way this question makes any sense whatsoever is if it's about the Marauder's Map. If you have another sensible interpretation, please share!

Comment: I'm not convinced. Those marks are all that is on the map. When the two professors made their separate trips to the Whomping Willow, both sets of H&H were in place. All I can say is this is an easy mistake to make in an otherwise exemplary work of fiction.